# React version not installed?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs

having some issues while trying [this repo](https://github.com/VctrySam/SnapChat) i found on GitHub while trying to learn.

I'm getting this every time i do the npm install

> npm WARN react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.2.0 requires a peer of
> react@^15.2.0 but none was installed.

and i cannot get pass this while simulating the app

[image]

I have tried many things and none of it seem to work, i had some other issues but i fixed them but i can't get pass this one!

any ideas?

Comment: not sure about the other problem but the warning can be fixed by 
'npm i -S react@15.2.0'

after this run 'npm i' again to make sure your packages are lined up and to filter our duplicate packages if any

Comment: @OzLodriguez the problem is caused by this (Or at least that's what i think).

i actually tried that before and i got this

`Manu$ npm i -S react@15.2.0
SnapChat@0.0.1 /Users/Manu/Desktop/SnapChat
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.2.0

npm WARN react-native@0.26.3 requires a peer of react@15.0.2 but none was installed.
npm ERR! code 1`

not sure what to do there

Comment: `npm install --save react`

Comment: @MikeDriver hey mike, now i get this `snapchat Manu$ npm install --save react
npm WARN react-native@0.26.3 requires a peer of react@15.0.2 but none was installed.`

I asked about this too in the react repo in github but i didnt get anything either